# Choosing Between CNC Lathe and Mill for my 3D Parts

Tags: cnc

I am on the verge of producing two parts in CNC Type III anodized aluminum, and was wondering what all your thoughts would be on whether to produce the parts on a CNC lathe or a CNC mill.

It is quite a complicated part, has a relatively cylindrical shape, though I wouldn't say it has too much rotational symmetry.
Each part is centered around a slot, and there are no threads or anything of the sort. Both parts would roughly take up 2.5cm² of material each

I am also minimizing the amount of square corners, but there will still have to be a few left at the end. I intend to produce upwards of 100 of each, and tight tolerances are necessary.

I have linked below the same parts I plan to replicate, you viewers will find a digital preview of the parts there. I have also linked pictures for your convenience. This has all been done with the approval of the original designer. Feel free to ask me any further questions about the parts :)

Thanks,

Dorian

[Part 1](https://www.shapeways.com/product/DV4FT7AAK/tao-bronze-gear-link-long-gear?optionId=322518738&li=shops)

[Part 2](https://www.shapeways.com/product/VERSCT2E6/tao-bronze-gear-link-short-gear?optionId=322519093&li=shops)

[image: Part 1 Picture]

[image: Part 2 Picture]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150972/discussion-on-question-by-dorian-surcel-choosing-between-cnc-lathe-and-mill-for); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

That looks to me like a job for DMLS (direct metal laser sintering). There are various approaches to this but the most suitable is probably the variety that builds up a "cake" of power, one layer at a time, and sinters the powder on the top layer. As a result very complex shapes can be made with minimal support and post-production machining.

With 20 mm max dimension I would expect that all 100 could be made in one run on most machines.

A YouTube search for [direct+metal+laser+sintering](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=direct+metal+laser+sintering) gives some insights. [Xometry Europe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxzFzbi0wF4) has a video with a good overview.